# PDO, mysql, utf8 (arabic text) doesnt show in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following php code. Connection is OK but it doesn't show the Arabic text stored in the database correctly. Just question marks.

```
$mysqlPDO = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOSTNAME.';charset=utf8;dbname='.DBNAME.'',DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8"));
$stmt =  $mysqlPDO->prepare("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'main_patches_version'");
$stmt->execute();
```

The DB collation is already set to utf8_general_ci and the table has utf8 as charset.
This application is calling Zend libraries which I'm not aware of.
I checked that the HTML has utf8 as encoding type. any suggestion?
I'm using xampp server, php version 5.5.11, mysql version 5.6.16

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Make sure the browser uses the correct charset. Sending a header helps too `header("Content-type: text/html; charset: UTF-8");`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I've added the header but no luck :( the static arabic text is displaying correctly when it's from the php code. but when it comes from the DB it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here
http://akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/

I unmarked 
`character_set_server=utf8` from my.ini file and it works.
Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your DB collation is set to use `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

Comment: the collation is already set to utf8_general_ci and the table has utf8 as charset

Comment: @AlShaikh What about the columns?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois not sure, but I have created a seperate php file that fetches the data from that table using PDO and display it. the Arabic text is showing correctly.